# Execute javascript when clicking on a wicket Resource Link

Tags: wicket

I have a wicket Resource link that generates and downloads a pdf file when Clicking on it.

```
 ResourceLink pdfResourceLink = new ResourceLink("dlPdf", new PdfResource() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public byte[] getPdf() {
            //code for generating pdf content
        }

        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return "file.pdf";
        }
    });
```

I want to block the page during the file generation to prevent user from doing any action. Is there a way to execute Javascript when clicking on a Resource Link ?

Comment: You may consider to override getOnClickScript to return the code to disable page while downloading. But the problem could be to re-enable page at the end of the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with the new AjaxDownload behavior that we are going to introduce in 7.7.0. The JIRA ticket is WICKET-6286 (I'm on my mobile so I might be wrong. Google it !). You can copy the code locally until it is officially released.

See AjaxDownloadPage.java in wicket-examples for demo.